Factoring in $\mathbb F[x,y]$.
I'm trying to factor the ideal $(x^3, y^3 - 1)$ over $\mathbb F_2[x,y]$. What I have so far is that $(x^3, y^3 - 1) = (x^3, y - 1)(x^3, y^2 + y + 1)$ but both of those can't be prime ideals of $\mathbb F_2[x,y]$ (there is a classification that I am aware of for prime ideals of $k[x,y]$) so they must factor further. Initially I thought that $(x^3,y-1) = (x,y - 1)^3$ but that can't be the case.
$\textbf{Motivation:}$ We are given a field $K = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root to $x^3 + 16x + 24$. We must factor the ideal $(2)$ over the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z[\alpha, \beta]$ where and $\beta$ is a root to $x^3 + 36x + 81$ (the author stated that this is in fact the presentation of the ring of integers)

Over $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$, we might not always be able to write an ideal as a product of ideals. But what is possible is to write an ideal as an intesection of primary ideals(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition).
The primary decomposition of your ideal is $$\langle x^3,y^3 + 1 \rangle = \langle x^3,y+1 \rangle \cap \langle x^3,y^2 +y +1 \rangle$$ But these primary ideals are comaximal and hence we infact have
$$\langle x^3,y^3 + 1 \rangle = \langle x^3,y+1 \rangle  \langle x^3,y^2 +y +1 \rangle$$
Coming to your ``motivation", the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ is not a dedekind domain, since $\theta = \frac{\alpha}{2}$ satisfes $x^3 + 4x + 3 = 0$ (I think the integral closure is $\mathbb{Z}[\theta,\beta]$ where $\theta = \frac{\alpha}{2}$)
Thus the best you can look for is a primary decomposition.
Anyway, the subring $\mathbb{Z}[\beta]$ is a Dedekind domain and we have a factorization $$2\mathbb{Z}[\beta] = \langle 2,\beta-1 \rangle \langle 2,\beta^2 + \beta + 1 \rangle$$
Now observe that since $\alpha^3 = -16\alpha-24$, $\alpha^3 \in \langle 2 \rangle$ and hence any prime ideal which contains $2$ contains $\alpha$. Thus if we consider $P = \langle 2 ,\beta-1 \rangle \mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$, then $P$ is contained in the unique prime ideal $\langle 2, \alpha,\beta-1 \rangle$. Similarly $Q = \langle 2,\beta^2 + \beta + 1 \rangle \mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ is contained in the unique prime ideal $\langle 2,\alpha,\beta^2 + \beta + 1 \rangle$. Since prime ideals are maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$, it follows that $P$ and $Q$ are primary ideals. Thus in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$, we get the primary decomposition $$ \langle 2 \rangle = PQ = \langle 2,\beta-1 \rangle \langle 2,\beta^2 + \beta + 1 \rangle$$.

Sorry I should have added that $\mathbb Z[\alpha, \beta]$ is indeed a Dedekind domain since it's the ring of integers of a certain field.

@A.Z it is not as I have remarked, $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ is not integrally closed in the fraction field, you need to adjoin $\theta = \frac{\alpha}{2}$.
